# Centering via offset math doesn't work in non-webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/LPF85/6/

In FF, IE7, and IE9 (the only browsers I've tested that don't run WebKit), it seems that the left attribute is either always set to `0`, or, in IE's case, negative.

My positioning code is all based off the dimensions of the document.

```
function open_img_in_face_box(id, width){
    max_width = $j(document).width();
    max_height = $j(document).height();
    padding = 150;

    passed_width = width || (max_width - (2 * padding));

    var img = $j('#' + id); 
    dom_img = document.getElementById(id); 

    $j(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { 
        $j("#facebox .image img").width(passed_width);
    })
    // display 
    jQuery.facebox({ 
        image: img.attr('src')
    });

    // center and adjust size
    var aspect_ratio = img.width() / img.height();
    var img_width = passed_width;
    var img_height = passed_width / aspect_ratio;

    window_center_y = max_height / 2;
    window_center_x = max_width / 2;

    offset_y = window_center_y - (img_height / 2);
    offset_x = window_center_x - (img_width / 2);

    var fbx = $j('#facebox');
    fbx.css('position', 'absolute');
    fbx.css('left', offset_x + 'px !important');
    fbx.css('top', offset_y + 'px !important');
    fbx.css('margin-left', 'auto');
    fbx.css('margin-right', 'auto');

}
```

`margin-left` and `margin-right` don't appear to do anything here, which I'm fine with, because the left math should work across all browsers, right? (It *is* just math)

The goal of the facebox / lightbox, is to be centered both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: what webkit browsers have you tried?

Comment: @MattBall -- FF is in the OP's list

Comment: Why don't you do positioning with css?

Comment: This seems to work just fine in Chrome for me (webkit). (*edit*) and it works in Safari ... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Pointy: I think there was a botched title edit, I've corrected it. TheLindyHop or others, please rollback if I've made a mistake.

Comment: FF is Gecko. @Wesley, thanks. I'm not doing positioning with CSS, because I have a pre-defined DIV that needs to be centered =\

Comment: @Wesley, thanks again, I just looked at the edit history. Apparently, some douche has been re-naming my titles to mean the opposite of what I'm saying... >_<  the original was not(webkit) I thought that was pretty self explanatory for anyone that programs. =\

Comment: "only works in webkit" would probably have been clearer.

Comment: I think "only works in webkit" is a bit too positive, and doesn't stress too much negativity. (but that's just my style)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you even programatically calculate the position in the first place? What if the user resizes the page? This can easily be done in pure CSS.

I don't really understand your jsFiddle (or am I not seeing the same thing?) so I'll just give you this script: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/8U4Ke/ that can be modified however you like. It's *commented*. ;)

Now it's easy to hide and show - to hide, fade out `.overlay`. To show, fade it in. To change the contents, replace the HTML in `.popup`. Add close boxes and whatnot liberally.

Comment: I haven't been doing CSS, because the div that needs to be centered is pre-defined. (ala, Facebox)

Comment: @TheLindyHop: So... don't use Facebox. It can easily be duplicated. jsFiddle updated to reflect that.

Comment: uhm... I don't think you understand why people use facebox. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @TheLindyHop: Because it requires you to write your own positioning that doesn't work, I suppose... unless FaceBox already does that? Then why are you writing your own? Maybe I don't quite understand your question, care to clarify?

Comment: yeah, facebox does already do that.. kinda. The trick i'm trying to do   is get the facebox to position itself relative to the document, rather than a containing div.